# Firebase function for my react app not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, function

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1280:14)`
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1328:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1415:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions- 
    framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/index.js:77:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

**The error shows port 8080 in use that I have checked of my port there is process using port 8080**

Comment: You need to change the port number to another for example 8585

Comment: I'm seeing this too. Any luck?

Comment: use `process.env.PORT` to get the port your app is intended to listen on from firebase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered this error after upgrading Node from 8 to 10. In my particular case, I was calling `app.listen` in my app, but Firebase Functions appears to set up the port automatically. Removing `app.listen(PORT, () => {})` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Create react app you can edit the package.json to be something like this:

`"start": "export PORT=3012 react-scripts start",`

then when you run `npm run start` it will boot up the app on port 3012.

you can also run this straight from the terminal like so: `PORT=3012 npm run start`

Comment: the error does not when i run the code locally. It occurs when I host it on firebase

Comment: you need to add more details to your question then

Comment: I have hosted my backend using firebase function but when I check my logs it displays an error of EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080

Comment: @sylvesterasa did you find any solution?